# TCPDF Custom font issue when converting SVG to PDF

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I've imported all my fonts to tcpdf using:

```
TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont($ttf, 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 96);
```

And now i'm converting full size SVG images to pdf pages:

```
$pdf->ImageSVG('@' . $svg, 0, 0, $width, $height, '', '', '', 0,
false);
```

And i'm getting three squares at the end of all texts, how i can remove them?
[image: Bug]

Link to svg: http://files.dangerd.org/pub/zzz/test.svg

Answer (score 1):

In the current TCPDF source code you can uncomment line 24418

```
$text = $this->stringTrim($text);
```

This did the trick for me, but I haven't tested it thoroughly and don't know why it is commented in the first place.